# Unable to instansiate subclass of CefV8Handler

Tags: handler, v8, chromium-embedded

Working off of the cefsimple application included with the Cef binaries, I'm trying to implement a javascript V8 handler for my Cef plugin. But I'm having some trouble. I've created a subclass named `SimpleV8Handler` which extends `CefV8Handler`. I implemented the `Execute` method, since I thought that was all you needed to do according to the tutorial, but I'm having problems trying to instantiate it from within `SimpleHandler::OnContextCreated()` via this line;

```
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> test_func = CefV8Value::CreateFunction("test_func", new SimpleV8Handler());
```

I'm told that I'm missing three virtual functions, `CefBase::AddRef`, `CefBase::Release` and `CefBase::HasOneRef`. I've tried adding the line `IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(SimpleV8Handler);` to the bottom of my handler's class in the .h file, but the errors didn't leave. What else am I missing; do I actually have to implement those methods myself? What should they do?

Comment: If you want to use the ```IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING``` macro in your class, you have to inherit from ```CefBase``` from ```cef_base.h```. Actually ```CefV8Handler``` inherits from ```CefBase```, so you should be fine. Have you managed to solve the issue? Could you post some code?

Comment: I have not solved the issue, nobody yet has given an answer. I've looked into the macro `IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING`, and it seems to define those methods for me automatically. However, I still get errors trying to instantiate the class, saying that the methods aren't implemented.

Comment: See the `unittests` project for an example https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/694b45717c971a0bb639f555b640d313fc15ccc8/tests/unittests/v8_unittest.cc?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#v8_unittest.cc-1149